# MVC framework Partial View URL change issue

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, partial-views

I have two pages. The first page does some calculation on load and clicking a url opens a second page.

I have implemented a partial view in my second .cshtml page. This partial view gets refreshed when I hit a button on the second page.

When I hit the button, it also changes my page's URL (browser url changes).

I didnt realise this was going to be an issue until I hit the back button (expecting to go back to the first page) instead it either goes back to the previous state of the partial view or throws an error. It doesn't go back to the first page.

Is this achievable through MVC? Am not a Java/Ajax person. Any suggestions to fix this ?

Ideally, if I can stop the urls from changing it might be good. Is it possible to refresh a page that has partial view without changing the url ?

This is the code inside my second page button that modifies data in my first page and forces a refresh of the partial view in my second page

```
<input style="float:left" type="submit" value="Select/Unselect all" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="SelectAllUsers" />
```

And this is the controller action

```
        public IActionResult SelectAllUsers()
        {
            // do some calculations         
            return View("SecondPage", afi);
        }
```

Comment: Yes, that is a common pattern. As you alluded to, you need to make an ajax call and then process the result. The partial can live on the same page until needed or pop it up in a modal.

Comment: How exactly is the partial view changing the URL?  I would expect any request from the client (form post, link click, etc.) to invoke a server-side action, and then return a view or redirect.  Since you say you're not using JavaScript then I assume this is all just links and form posts?  Maybe I'm missing something, the nature of the problem is just unclear to me.

Comment: Just modified my original post to add the code/implementation. thanks

Comment: EF is an ORM, MVC is a web framework. They are *completely* different things. EF is used to load data from the database, not render it as HTML

Comment: thanks for pointing out. removed EF mentions.

Comment: Typically you would have a controller action that returns a PartialViewResult (not a View). Then in script you insert that into, say, a div `$('#myDiv').html(myresult);`. Lots of examples if you search MVC Ajax PartialView. [Here](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Return-Partial-View-from-Controller-using-AJAX-in-ASPNet-MVC.aspx) is one.

Comment: Thank you. Looks like I have to use Ajax.